# Organic Group activity with grouped results

Tags: 7, views, organic-groups

I'm currently running a D7 system and want to build an admin-only view of Organic Group activity.

I want that view to have two exposed filters:

- Group name
- Date posted

In a nutshell  user should be able to select the 'group name' and 'date posted' and gets presented with a list of content which was posted within the group X form 'x date' to 'y date'.

Something like:
Following items has been posted in the group 'X'

- news total 32
- webforms total 12
- galleries total 10

Any help would be much appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I achieved this by creating two different views and two exposed filters:

**Filters**
 - Group id
 - Date filter 
**Views**
 - View 1 with content base table
 - View 2 with comments base table

.Then I have used views aggregation to present results